# Can't Loop through javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is a javascript quiz done with `for` loops. The problem is when 2 of the same answers are selected (such as "Dec" and "Dec"), the program is scoring them as 2 correct answers.

Please review the code. It seems as if the program is looping all the selected options, and checking them against the answers.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Multiple Choice Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1">
            When is xmas?<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Jan" >Jan<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Dec" >Dec<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Feb" >Feb<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="June" >June<br/>
        </form>

        <form name="form2">
            When is thanksgiving?<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Jan" >Jan<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Dec" >Dec<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Feb" >Feb<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Nov" >Nov<br/>
        </form>

        <form name="form3">
            What month is Arbor Day in the U.S?<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Mar" >Mar<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="April" >April<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="June" >June<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="July" >July<br/>
        </form>

        <form name="form4">
            What month is Bastille Day?<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Mar" >Mar<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="April" >April<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="June" >June<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="July" >July<br/>
        </form>

        <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" onClick="getAnswer()">
        <br/>
        <div id="score"></div>

        <script>
            var questAns = [
                ["What month is xmas?", "Dec" ],
                ["What month is Thanksgiving?", "Nov" ],
                ["What month is Arbor Day in the U.S?", "April"],
                ["What month is Bastille Day?", "July"]
            ]

            function getAnswer() {
                score = 0;
                numQuestions = 4; //the numbe of questions in the test
                numCorrectAns = 4 //the total number of correct answers in the test
                numAnswers = 4; //the number of answers per questions

                for (i=0; i< numQuestions; i++) {
                    for (j=0; j< numAnswers; j++) {
                        for (a=0; a < numCorrectAns; a++) {
                            if (document.forms[i].answer[j].checked && document.forms[i].answer[j].value === questAns[a][1]) {
                                score = score + 25;
                                // alert("correct, your score is " + score + " and the answer is " + questAns[a][1]);
                                //alert((document.forms[0].answer[0].value));
                                //alert("the 2nd answer is " + questAns[a][1]); 
                            }
                            else {
                                score = score + 0;
                                //alert("wrong, your score is " + score);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } //end of 

                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "<h3>Score: " + score + "</h3>";

                //This displays your score
                document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;//This disables the submit button so user can't change answers
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your logic for checking whether an answer is right is overly-complicated. It would probably be better to check 1 form at a time

Answer (score 0):

You did it pretty complicated, and probably, you would do better using other approach.

That´s the working code, anyway:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Multiple Choice Test</title>
</head>



<body>
<form name="form1">
When is xmas?<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Jan" >Jan<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Dec" >Dec<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Feb" >Feb<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="June" >June<br/>
</form>

<form name="form2">
When is thanksgiving?<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Jan" >Jan<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Dec" >Dec<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Feb" >Feb<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Nov" >Nov<br/>
</form>

<form name="form3">
What month is Arbor Day in the U.S?<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Mar" >Mar<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="April" >April<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="June" >June<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="July" >July<br/>
</form>

<form name="form4">
What month is Bastille Day?<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Mar" >Mar<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="April" >April<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="June" >June<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="July" >July<br/>
</form>

<input type="submit" id="mySubmit" onClick="getAnswer()">
<br/>
<div id="score"></div>

</body>

</html>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var questAns = [
    ["What month is xmas?", "Dec" ],
    ["What month is Thanksgiving?", "Nov" ],
    ["What month is Arbor Day in the U.S?", "April"],
    ["What month is Bastille Day?", "July"]

]
function getAnswer() {
    score = 0;
    numQuestions = 4; //the numbe of questions in the test
    numCorrectAns = 4 //the total number of correct answers in the test
    numAnswers = 4; //the number of answers per questions

    for (i=0; i< numQuestions; i++) {

        for (j=0; j< numAnswers; j++) {

            if (document.forms[i].answer[j].checked && document.forms[i].answer[j].value === questAns[i][1]){
                    console.log("i: "+i+", j:"+j+", a:"+i);

                    score = score + 25;
                    // alert("correct, your score is " + score + " and the answer is " + questAns[a][1]);
                     //alert((document.forms[0].answer[0].value));
                     //alert("the 2nd answer is " + questAns[a][1]); 
                    }
                else {
                    score = score + 0;  
                    //alert("wrong, your score is " + score);       
                    }
            }

    }//end of 

    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "<h3>Score: " + score + "</h3>";

//This displays your score
        document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;    //This disables the submit button so user can't change answers
}
</script>
```

What you were doing wrong is to iterate over all entries in questAns array, when you really had a direct match between that array and the list of questions in your form, so, for the comparation, you had to use the same index to get addecuate results.

Since I said it was a bit complicated, I will suggest you another approach to solve this.

You could use in each form a parameter indicating the correct answer, and use it to compare(jquery required):

```
...
<form name="form1" data-answer="Dec">
    When is xmas?<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Jan" >Jan<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Dec" >Dec<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Feb" >Feb<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="June" >June<br/>
 </form>
....
```

And then, in javascript:

```
...
score = 0;
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(index, checked_input){
   if ($(checked_input).val() == $(checked_input).parent().attr("data-answer")) score+=25;
});
...
```

Comment: That works great! Should I focus more on jquery or original javascript?

Comment: I think you´d better focus on jquery, but don´t forget to learn the basics of javascript, it will give you a wider vision.